# Why there is an error when running glmmTMB() in RStudio version 2022.02.0?

Tags: model, version, glmmtmb

i am trying to run a Poisson GLMM model:

```
m <- glmmTMB(length ~ temp + site + temp:site, family = poisson, data = df)
```

but i get an error message:

Error in .Call("getParameterOrder", data, parameters, new.env(), PACKAGE = DLL) :
Incorrect number of arguments (3), expecting 4 for 'getParameterOrder'

I reinstalled 'glmmTBM', restarted RStudio but the error retained.
Incorporating more variables into the model doesn't help - the error message persists.

The RStudio version is 2022.02.0 and the R version is 4.1.0.

Can anyone help me please what i am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, and a simple update to R 4.2.0 did solve it.

Comment: having the same issue with R version 4.3.1